# how much memory would a byte array consume when loaded with a file contens in C#

Tags: c#, file, memory, arrays, .net

When we create a byte array like this:

```
byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("FileName.exe");
```

Will the size of the file take up the memory?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Size in bytes: {0} , Size in KB: {1}", fileData.Length, fileData.Length / 1024);` I just checked it with a file size of 97KB, it shows: `Size in bytes: 99328 , Size in KB: 97`, plus you can add 4 bytes on 32 bit OS or 8 bytes on 64 bit OS for the reference

Comment: thanks @Habib, your answer lead me to some different thinking and I found out this article to be usefull [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/byte-array)

Comment: I wonder why this question is 'closed as not a real question', though it has got two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The File.ReadAllBytes method is implemented in a pretty obvious way. It uses the using resource acquisition block on a FileStream. Then, it loops through the file and puts the bytes into a byte array. In the .NET Framework 4.0, it will throw an exception if the file exceeds 2 gigabytes.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readallbytes

Answer (score 2):

Anywhere from 0 bytes up, me thinks...

You would probaly think that it depends on the actual size of the file?

Comment: @J.Steen that is what i wanted to know, for if the file is 100MB in size, after loading the array, will it consume the memory by an extra 100MB?

Comment: @J.Steen Over the top a little?